# General Styling for the Whole iOS App

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, styling

I am fairly new at creating iOS apps and I have a question about a common practice regarding central Text & Color styling in a project.

What I want to do is to define a custom "Header" style, custom "ToolBar" style, custom "Body" style etc. and use them in different UIControlViews in my project.

I want to be able to change one of these styles so that every object using that style adjusts accordingly.

As much as I understand there are no CSS-like styling files when designing an iOS app.

What I was thinking to do is to create a Swift file where my styles are defined as constants in some way and add code blocks in all `viewDidLoad` methods of `UIViewController`s that sets related objects' styles by using these constants.

Is there a better way, or what is the common practice for doing that kind of thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many classes has the protocol `UIAppearance` which sets their default properties such as font, textColor, backgroundColor etc.

Ex:

```
UIButton.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

[List of all classes using UIAppearance](https://gist.github.com/mattt/5135521)

Comment: This is the correct way. Or subclassing for even more detailed control.

Comment: Yes of course, subclassing gives you more control than UIAppearance .)

Comment: Thanks a lot! For a small project this is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

As you said create a configuration.swift file that contains your configuration and returns a view based on configuration  and then use this configuration to create a custom view. This is the way I did in my last app. Also, check this snippet to get an actual understanding of what I said http://www.objc.io/snippets/20.html

Comment: I am using Arbitur's solution for now although for bigger projects I tend to go your way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Read about view controller polymorphism and view controller hierarchy.

Base a "parent" view controller on `UITableViewController`, and include your common properties and methods.

Then base all the "child" view controllers on that "parent".

For example in Objective C:

"Parent" view controller header file...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyParentTableViewController : UITableViewController

@end
```

"Child" view controller header file...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyChildTableViewController : MyParentTableViewController

@end
```

So in this manner all public properties and methods of the parent become available to the child, and only need be written once, in the parent implementation file.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the pod [NUI](https://github.com/tombenner/nui) for styling the complete iphone Application. There are couple of other options like [UISS](https://github.com/robertwijas/UISS).

There are few other commercial options also, but the above two do a fantastic job of externalizing the styling of the application.

I've used NUI and it enables me to provide multiple themes and even allow the end user to switch themes.